# Handling JSONObject Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I am using `JSONObject` to build a JSON response.  The problem I'm facing is how to handle the exception that `.put()` throws.  I surrounded my code with a try catch, but I want to output JSON in my catch as well. I've been doing this by hand as seen below, but this seems prone to errors.What is the right way to handle this exception?

```
try{
    myResponse.put("successful",true);
    resp.getOutputStream().print(myeResponse.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    resp.getOutputStream().print("{\"successful\":false, \"error\":\"Changes could not be saved.  Please reload the page and try again.\"}");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to figure out is when the `put()` method of `JSONObject` would throw `JSONException`.

From the [Javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

```
public JSONObject put(java.lang.String key,
                      boolean value)
               throws JSONException

Put a key/boolean pair in the JSONObject.

Parameters:
    key - A key string.
    value - A boolean which is the value. 
Returns:
    this. 
Throws:
    JSONException - If the key is null.
```

So, all you need to take care is that your key is not null which would surely be the case because your key is `"successful"`.

Comment: So I can be confident this exception will never be thrown and know the other json will never be used?

Comment: JSONException can be also be thrown for non-numbers, i.e. infinite values or NaN values of Double, Integer, etc.  Watch out for those in other use cases (clearly won't happen to code in OP, but this should be stated in case someone tries to generalize from this answer)